# Перебором элементов списка перейти к первому элементу?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Необходимо это сделать с помощью чистого JS или jQuery

Есть список элементов:

```
<div>
    <div class="mobile-block">
    <ul class="mobile-list">
        <h2>Автомобильные шины</h2>
        <li class="active">
          <p>Текст</p>
        </li>
        <h2>Мототехника</h2>
        <li>
          <p>Текст</p>
        </li>
        <h2>Лодочные моторы</h2>
        <li>
          <p>Текст</p>
        </li>
        <h2>Надувные лодки</h2>
        <li>
          <p>Текст</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Необходимо с интервалом в 1,5 секунды:

1. Находить элемент списка с классом .active ("Один") и убирать у него данный класс
2. Находить следующий элемент в списке ("Два") и добавлять ему класс .active

Проблема в том, когда скрипт доходит до последнего элемента списка ("Четыре"). Как сделать так, чтобы доходя до последнего элемента списка - скрип следующим элементом выбирал первый в списке ("Один")?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
setInterval(function(){
  var items = $(".mobile-list li");
  var index = (items.index($(".mobile-list li.active")) + 1) % items.length;
  items.removeClass("active").eq(index).addClass("active");
}, 1500);
```

```css
.active {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div class="mobile-block">
    <ul class="mobile-list">
        <h2>Автомобильные шины</h2>
        <li class="active">
          <p>Текст</p>
        </li>
        <h2>Мототехника</h2>
        <li>
          <p>Текст</p>
        </li>
        <h2>Лодочные моторы</h2>
        <li>
          <p>Текст</p>
        </li>
        <h2>Надувные лодки</h2>
        <li>
          <p>Текст</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```